# SSRS Matrix cells formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a data that looks like similar to below.

Data:

```
Type   Color
Pen    Black
Pen    Blue
Pen    Red
Pencil Black
Pencil Red
```

I am trying to use it to show the desired result in ssrs which is shown below.

Desired Result:

```
Pen    Pencil
Black  Black
Blue   Red
Red
```

Current Issue:

```
Pen    Pencil
Black  Black
Blue
Red    Red
```

I am getting empty rows which I want to remove. If anyone can provide an example on how to format it appropriately, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to nest a table in the matrix detail.

In the matrix, drag a table to the detail textbox.
Remove table header and footer and leave one column in the detail.
Set the table to have the same dataset as the matrix and filter the table with the Type field.

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]